# ASP.NET conflict with JQuery

Tags: jquery, webforms

I am developing with JQuery and JQuery UI, actually I am using datepicker widget. I need to change language and I download a language library for it (it is Italian):

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.datepicker.regional['it'] = {
    /* ... */
  };
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
});
```

In my code I use it in this way:

```
$(function () {
  $("#TextBoxStartDate").datepicker();
  $("#TextBoxEndDate").datepicker();
});
```

In this way I had an error like this:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

I tried to use the same form of the library to load the datepickers:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#TextBoxStartDate").datepicker();
  $("#TextBoxEndDate").datepicker();
});
```

And it works! But I don't understand why. Anyone can explain it to me?

**UPDATE:** My problem was a conflict one beetween two instances of jQuery. It was loaded twice because I insert it as script manager in ASP.NET application (I need it to keep work with client-side control of ASP.NET web forms).
ASP.NET load it into the body, within the view state, and I loaded it into the head, so they collapse themselves. I moved jquery-ui, and other scripts that use jquery into the body, and it fixes the problem.
Only one thing remain unexplained: why it worked if I used `jQuery(function($) {`?!?!

Comment: Do you have other libraries that use the arbitrary `$()` function?

Comment: When you use `jQuery` instead of the `$` and it works that to me indicates some sort of namespace collision. Perhaps you are including multiple jQuery versions, or you are including a library which is overwriting the `$`. Check which scripts you are loading, and the order of them. If that doesn't help, at least edit the question with which relevant scripts are included.

Comment: There are no other scripts over jquery, jquery-ui, language library for datepicker and my script. If it can help, I use ASP.NET with web forms, but it didn't seems to me much important so I didn't include it in the question.

Comment: If can help, if I try to replace `jQuery(function($){` in language library with `$(function () {` I get the error into it.

Comment: I tryed also to replace `$` with `jQuery` without success.